# How to Make My one column list to Multiple column in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP query list from the database, but It's showing only one column.[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9wTq.png)

I want this in two separate columns.[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhXr9.png)

When I am using `<table>`, it's showing me two separate columns but don't showing unique results. Showing the same result again

How I will do it?

```
<?php
$query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bit_gateways ORDER BY id");
if($query2->num_rows>0) {
    while($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <img src="<?php echo gatewayicon($row['name']); ?>" width="42px" height="42px" class="img-circle img-bordered pull-left">
        <span class="pull-left" style="margin-left:5px;">
            <span style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $row['name']." ".$row['currency']; ?></span><br/>
            <span class="text text-muted"><?php echo $row['reserve']." ".$row['currency']; ?> </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php echo $lang['no_have_gateways']; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<div class="row"></div>` , since bootstrap 4 changes display to "flex" and if you want to combine the cols and want them showing beside each other or next to each other the "row" will do the job.

Comment: I already have <div class="row"></div> but not showing result side by side. it's showing in one column , one by one